# $_POST is not doing what I expect

Tags: php, html, http-post

I am displaying a table from a MySQL db. I want to use pull downs in each column to filter the table. I want to do it dynamically without using a submit button.

As you will see from the code and pictures, I have almost managed to do this, but the data being returned in `$_POST` is confusing.

First: `$_POST[name]`, `$_POST[car]` and `$_POST[color]` all return the first value regardless of whether that select function has been selected. why is this? I have coded around that (as you will see)

Second: If I select 'Bob', the code works the first time, but if I select 'Bob' again, `$_POST` acts like it is empty. huh?

What am I doing wrong with what I thought was basic code. I have looked high and low on this site and on the internet to try and find a more detailed explanation on how $_POST functions in this regard.

```php
<?php
//connect to database
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', "masterlist");

//get the column names from the masterlist table
$get_list_sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM listTest";
$get_list_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_list_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

//display_block contains the HTML form data to display
$display_block = "<h1>QLD RNE Design Master List</h1>";
$display_block .="<form action='listTest.php' method='POST'>";
$display_block .="<table><tr>";

//.............................Display field names as header..................................................................

//loop through all the fields, ignore the id field as we don't display it
  while ($list = mysqli_fetch_array($get_list_res)) {
    if ($list['Field'] <> 'id') {

        // simplify the data by using a string to store the current field name
        $Field = $list['Field'];

        // build select for the field
        $display_block .= "<td align = 'center'>".$Field."</td>";
    }
}
$display_block .="</tr><tr>";

//.............................Display Sorting options..................................................................

//loop through all the fields, ignore the id field as we don't display it
$get_list_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_list_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

$get_list_sql = "SELECT * from listTest order by name";
  while ($list = mysqli_fetch_array($get_list_res)) 
  {
    if ($list['Field'] <> 'id') 
    {
        // get the unique list of data in the field to use in the select field for filtering
        $SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT ".$list['Field']." from listTest ORDER BY ".$list['Field']." ASC ";
        $get_list = mysqli_query($mysqli, $SQL) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)) ;  

        // simplify the data by using a string to store the current field name
        $Field = $list['Field'];

        if(isset($_POST[$Field]) && $_POST[$Field] <> $Field)
        {
            echo($Field.' should have been pressed and has a value of '.$_POST[$Field].'<br>');
            $get_list_sql = "SELECT * from listTest where ".$Field." ='" .$_POST[$Field]. "' order by name";
            $name = $_POST[$Field];
        }else
        {
            $name = $Field;
        }
        echo ('name = '.$name.'<br>');

        // build select for the field
        $display_block .= "<td align = 'center'><select name ='".$name."' id='".$Field."' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";

        //set the first option to the field name
        $display_block .= "<option value=".$Field.">".$Field."</option>";

        //loop through the data list
        while ($select = mysqli_fetch_array($get_list)) 
        {
            if ($select[$Field]<>null)
            {
                $display_block .= "<option value=".$select[$Field].">".$select[$Field]."</option>";
            }
        }
        $display_block .="</select></td>";
    }
}

//.............................Display Data..................................................................

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
{
        echo "<pre><tr>";
        echo "<td> ";
        echo $key;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td> ";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr></pre>";
}

echo($get_list_sql );

$get_list_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_list_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
  while ($list = mysqli_fetch_array($get_list_res)) 
{
    $display_block .= "<tr><td>".$list['name']."
        </td><td>".$list['color']."
        </td><td>".$list['car']."
        </td>";
}
//echo('finished');
$display_block .="</tr>";
$display_block .="</form></table>";

//free results
mysqli_free_result($get_list_res);

//close connection to MySQL
mysqli_close($mysqli);
//$_POST = array();


//.............................HTML.................................................................
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css">
<head>
<style>
h1 {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #cc9900;
    color: #996600;
    font-size: 20px;
}
table, th , td {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;

}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<?php echo $display_block; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

since I can only paste 12 link here is an example of the code running. Fist image is the start, the second is selecting 'bob' and the third is selecting 'bob' a second time:

[image]

I hope somebody can help, and please don't suggest I write this in another language. I want it in PHP. I am using Chrome as a web browser

Comment: One thing I find really useful when solving these types of issues is viewing the source of the data I'm creating when I'm doing this programatically.  Enter Bob for your value, check the page source, then resubmit it and look again.  The problem is likely in the block of code here: ```if(isset($_POST[$Field]) && $_POST[$Field] <> $Field)```

Comment: good tip DaOgre but it doesn't help me in this case because its only displaying what I tell it to and that's right.

Comment: You have some obvious errors in that HTML which would be picked up by https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: This would be a lot easier to debug if you looked at the interstitial states. You're showing some PHP which generates some HTML which includes a form that the browser submits back to PHP. Look at the HTML you generate.